# Join com várias condições

Tags: sql, lógica, join

Tenho duas tabelas e preciso uni-las trazendo o resultado através das seguintes condições:

O `Numero_tel_origem` e `Numero_tel_dest` da tabela 1, tem que ser o mesmo `Numero_tel_origem` `Numero_tel_dest` da tabela 2.

Ex.:

```
Tabela 1
Numero_tel_origem = 000001 
Numero tel_dest = 10000  

Tabela 2
Numero_tel_origem = 000001 
Numero tel_dest = 10000
```

Precisa ser verdadeiro as duas condições que estão na mesma linha das tabelas.

Como posso fazer o join?

```
select * from tabela1 a
inner join tabela2 b on a.Numero_tel_origem = b.Numero_tel_origem AND a.Numero_tel_dest = b.Numero_tel_dest
```

Comment: Esse exemplo não funcionou de join que você colocou não funcionou?

Comment: Não, pq primeiro ela valida se o numero_tel_origem é o mesmo nas duas tabelas pra depois validar o numero_tel_dest. Eu preciso que a validação ocorra no mesmo tempo. 
Não sei se consegui explicar direito...

Comment: Então o número origem tem que ser igual entre as duas tabelas OU o número destino tem que ser igual? Da sua forma, ambos precisam ser igual, isso é uma regra ou se um condição atender a outra não precisa ser verificada? Se for isso, você não deve usar um AND, deve usar um OR.

Comment: Ambos precisam ser o mesmo... por exemplo: eu fiz 3 ligacões durante o dia para você e mais duas pessoas diferentes (tabela 2), na tabela 1 constam 3 ligacões para você. Eu preciso trazer da tabela 2 apenas a ligação que fiz pra você.

Comment: Não tem sentido você falar em ordem de avaliação, "primeiro valida .. e depois valida ...". Com o operador AND as duas cláusulas precisam ser satisfeitas, independente da ordem em que forem avaliadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a clausula WHERE pra condição:

```
select * from tabela1 a, tabela2 b
WHERE
a.Numero_tel_dest = b.Numero_tel_dest
AND
a.Numero_tel_origem = b.Numero_tel_origem
```

Comment: Caso não seja isso, me avise para que eu possa entender melhor e te ajudar

Comment: Gabriel, me ajudou muito! Muito obrigada!